# Animator transition automatically resetting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some basic walking animations, when the user wants to turn the walking animation transitions to a turning animation.

The problem I have is in the animator controller, I change the values here to make the transition more smooth, but it keeps on resetting after I click away. I've tried saving after changing it and clicking away, pressed enter after putting in a new value. It still keeps resetting to the previous value. Googling didn't help.

Is there a workaround to prevent this from happening?

Comment: If you are setting the values while your debug game is on the values are not saved. You need to stop the game and then set the values.

Comment: I don't think I've got anything in Debug or playmode